# handle web browser link event in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I am using WP7 WebBrowser control . On this page I have a hyperlink.This link are came from web service. I want to handle the click event of that hyperlink in my application's code behind (i.e. in C#).And i want display another web browser controll on this hyperlink click event

Is there are a way for the WebBrowser control to handle click events?

Comment: On which control u need to an event,Button/webbrowser?Your question is not clear.

Comment: @yogesh:sorry but i need event on hyperlink which is on my web browser controll

Comment: Did u create the hyperlink?Which page your webbrowser loading your local html or online?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189711/wp7-open-another-web-browser-control-inside-web-broser-control  I think he is loading html from the web

Comment: If u doing it on web,u cant alter some others page click event.If it is your local HTML then you can write HTML code for loading new page.

Comment: @yogesh Actually, it doesn't matter what domain the webbrowser control is loading, he can alter the event (onClick event) or any other property accessible by the DOM in his webbrowser control instance, now matter where it is loaded from. check out my answer.

Comment: Actully i have http link in my web browser controll and this link is came from html and i set id on my link click event. i mean when i press link than one id is generated and i wants get this id and pass.so i open new page

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, you want to intercept the onClick event in your first WB control (call this WB1), and open that page up (when the hyperlink is clicked) in another WB control (call this WB2)?

There are several ways you can do this, is this link set to open up in a new window? If so, you can intercept the NewWindow2 event is WB1 and run the following code in the NewWindow2 event of WB1...

```
Set pDisp = WB2.object
```

(it may be ppDisp instead of pDisp, but it will show up when your event is auto generated, choose whichever object name shows up in your arguments list).

Otherwise, you can intercept this request during BeforeNavigate2 event of the WB1 event, check the URL property if it is the link you're interested in, and if so, cancel the current request and reissue a new one as below... (in the WB1 BN2 event)...

```
Cancel = True ' This cancels the request
WB2.Navigate2 URL, , "YourWB2sDocumentNameOrTargetFrameNameGoesHere"
```

Second line of code just reissues the request.

Of course, the YourWB2sDocumentNameOrTargetFrameNameGoesHere is the TargetFrameName (or the frame or document name of the top level document, or any iframe, in your WB2 control/window). This can usually be found in the BODY tags name= property, but you don't even need to do this if all you want is to load it as the top level document in WB2... if you just want to load it as the parent top level document in WB2, just do this...

```
Cancel = True
WB2.Navigate2 URL
```

By referencing WB2 it will just send the same URL request to WB2 window after cancelling WB1 request.

Let me know if you need more help and let me know how you get along.

Comment: thanks but how i handle event of content which is inside my wb1 control.let see i just want to open new form or wb when i click on my first wb control content. and my first wb control contain are came from data base and it is text and hyper link both but i just want handle hyper link event

Comment: @MaaN Well, did it work? To do what you want, all you really need to do is intercept the request during the BeforeNavigate2 event, cancel it (Cancel = True), and then re-send that request to your second WB Control (say, its named "WB2"), and the code would be "WB2.Navigate2 URL" - where the URL is provided by the BeforeNavigate2 event, viewabel in its argument signature when the events code is auto-generated for you when you select it from the list of events in the event list dropdown menu. The "Cancel" argument is also provided by the BeforeNavigate2 auto-generated event arugment signature.

Comment: @ Erx_VB.NExT.Coder:Please give me example so i can understand well...bcos i am not able to understand your answer'

Comment: @ Erx_VB.NExT.Coder:i just want to handle link event of my web broser control.i.e when i click on hyperlink of WB control at that time open new form

Comment: @MaaN do you see how i've posted the code in my answer? In your WB1_BeforeNavigate2 event, add the code above, which is just this:

Cancel = True
WB2.Navigate2 URL

This is in VB, so change to C# and you'd just need to place ; at the end of each line:

Cancel = True;
WB2.Navigate2 URL;

Tell me if it worked? Of course, don't forget to make your second WebBrowser Control named as "WB2", ok?

Comment: Does BeforeNavigate2 event even exist on Windows Phone WebBrowser? For me, the project doesn't compile when I try to use BeforeNavigate2.